# pattern matching with nested json response attributes

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to set vars after getting the response from `get_public_request` function. I refer to `var1` and `var2` in the following code sample:

```
def get_prices(item) do
    url = item_path(item)
    response = get_public_request(url)
    var1 = response["item"]["buy"]
    var2 = response["item"]["sell"]
end

def get_public_request(url) do
    HTTPoison.start
    case HTTPoison.get(url) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
        Poison.decode!(body)
    ...
    end
end
```

The response I'm getting (after Poison.decocode) looks like this:

```
%{"at" => 1536333060, "item" => %{"buy" => "8971.71", "area" => "A16", "sell" => "9019.89"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you’ve provided, everything you need in `get_prices` are these two params. The option would be to return them explicitly from `get_public_request`:

```rb
def get_public_request(url) do
  HTTPoison.start
  case HTTPoison.get(url) do
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
      with %{"item" => %{"buy" => buy, "sell" => sell}} <- Poison.decode!(body),
        do: {buy, sell}
    ...
    end
end
```

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) will return any unmatched RHO as is, hence if we get inside `do` we have what we need. Call it as:

```rb
def get_prices(item) do
  url = item_path(item)
  {var1, var2} = get_public_request(url)
end
```

---

If you expect them to be not always present in the response, use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#case/2):

```rb
def get_public_request(url) do
  HTTPoison.start
  case HTTPoison.get(url) do
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
      case Poison.decode!(body) do
        %{"item" => %{"buy" => buy, "sell" => sell}} -> {buy, sell}
        %{"item" => %{"buy" => buy}} -> {buy, nil}
        %{"item" => %{"sell" => sell}} -> {nil, sell}
        _ -> {nil, nil}
      end
    ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @mudasobwa, I would do the data extraction in the `get_public_request` but with one of those two other syntax:

#### pattern matching on a map

```rb
def get_prices(item), do:
    %{"buy":var1, "sell": var2} = item_path(item) |> get_public_request do 

def get_public_request(url) do
    HTTPoison.start
    case HTTPoison.get(url) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
        Poison.decode!(body)["item"] |> Map.take(["buy", "sell"])
    ...
    end
end
```

NB: this solution will crash during the pattern matching if one of the two fields "buy" or "sell" is missing. you can avoid that using `case`.

#### pattern matching on a tuple

```rb
def get_prices(item), do: {var1, var2} = item_path(item) |> get_public_request
def get_public_request(url) do
    HTTPoison.start
    case HTTPoison.get(url) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
        Poison.decode!(body)["item"] |> (&({&1["buy"],&1["sell"]}).()
    ...
    end
end
```

if you want to handle the case when there is data or not in the field you can add the following checking:

```rb
Poison.decode!(body)["item"] |> (&({Map.has_key?(&1,"buy") && &1["buy"] || nil, Map.has_key?(&1,"sell") && &1["sell"] || nil}).()
```